# how can I make a function in JS that gives me [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] = [4, 1, 2, 5, 3, 6]

Tags: javascript, function, loops

it should add all the arrays that doesnt exist, each new array created hold 6 numbers each number of those is ranged between 1 and 42 and then its pushed to the existing array wish hold the new arrays, the order of the numbers inside each array doesnt matter, meanwhile if i have [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]] it should not push a new array like this [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5]]

```js
let num = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]];
function creatList(){
  for(let f=0; f < 100; f++){
  {
      for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        var newnum = [];
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 42) +1;
        newnum.push(y);
      }
      if(
        newnum[0] == newnum[1] || newnum[0] == newnum[2] || newnum[0] == newnum[3] || newnum[0] == newnum[4] || newnum[0] == newnum[5] && newnum[1] == newnum[1] || newnum[1] == newnum[2] || newnum[1] == newnum[3] || newnum[1] == newnum[4] || newnum[1] == newnum[5] && newnum[2] == newnum[1] || newnum[2] == newnum[2] || newnum[2] == newnum[3] || newnum[2] == newnum[4] || newnum[2] == newnum[5] && newnum[3] == newnum[1] || newnum[3] == newnum[2] || newnum[3] == newnum[4] || newnum[3] == newnum[5] || newnum[4] == newnum[1] || newnum[4] == newnum[2] || newnum[4] == newnum[3] || newnum[4] == newnum[5] && newnum[5] == newnum[1] || newnum[5] == newnum[2] || newnum[5] == newnum[3] || newnum[5] == newnum[4]) newnum=[];

      for(let i = 0; i < num.length;  i++) {
      if(
        newnum[0] == num[i][1] || newnum[0] == num[i][2] || newnum[0] == num[i][3] || newnum[0] == num[i][4] || newnum[0] == num[i][5] && 
        newnum[1] == num[i][1] || newnum[1] == num[i][2] || newnum[1] == num[i][3] || newnum[1] == num[i][4] || newnum[1] == num[i][5] && 
        newnum[2] == num[i][1] || newnum[2] == num[i][2] || newnum[2] == num[i][3] || newnum[2] == num[i][4] || newnum[2] == num[i][5] && 
        newnum[3] == num[i][1] || newnum[3] == num[i][2] || newnum[3] == num[i][4] || newnum[3] == num[i][5] && 
        newnum[4] == num[i][1] || newnum[4] == num[i][2] || newnum[4] == num[i][3] || newnum[4] == num[i][5] && 
        newnum[5] == num[i][1] || newnum[5] == num[i][2] || newnum[5] == num[i][3] || newnum[5] == num[i][4]) num.push([]);
      else num.push(newnum);   
     }
      
    }
  }
  num.push(newnum);
  console.log(num);
}
creatList();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="/jsTest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

to code i think this is a bit advanced problem

Comment: please add what you want. do you want a random array or all permutations of an array?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question doesn't make any sense

Comment: indexOf() or includes

Comment: `i want this function to create all the possible arrays generated of 6 digits in range of 1 to 42` is very different to `how can I make a function in JS that gives me [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] = [4, 1, 2, 5, 3, 6]` so Im not sure what you're asking

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! please try to make your question clearer and if possible give an example of what you want to chieve

Comment: One part says you want all permutations, another part says it needs to have numbers up to 42? I have no clue exactly what you are asking.

Comment: is this what you want to say ?? 

I want to create a function that creates a matrix with all possible permutations of numbers in the range 1 to 42.
The matrix is a 7 X 6 matrix

I am trying to generate the matrix by creating a new row of random numbers and checking if that row already exists in my current matrix.

my code didn't word and i don't know how to break this function

Comment: it should add all the arrays that doesnt exist, each new array created hold 6 numbers each number of those is ranged between 1 and 42 and then its pushed to the existing array wish hold the new arrays, the order of the numbers inside each array doesnt matter, meanwhile if i have [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]] it should not push a new array like this [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5]]

Comment: i'd delete duplicates from those arrays, sort them and compare.

Answer (score 0):

You could just sort the arrays, serialize them with `JSON.stringify` and then compare the first array to all the other arrays.

```js
/**
 * Checks if every array is equal to one another
 * @param {Function} compFn - comparator function
 * @param {...Array} arr - zero or more arrays to compare
 * return {boolean} Returns false if the argument count is < 2,
          else each subsequent array is compared to the first
 */
const arraysEqual = (compFn, ...arr) => arr.length < 2
  ? false
  : arr.map(x => JSON.stringify(x.sort(compFn)))
    .slice(1).every((x, i, a) => x === a[0]);
  
console.log(arraysEqual(undefined, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 1, 2, 5, 3, 6]));
```